# Trying to refactor the code where I customize faces

Tags: themes, faces

I'm trying to switch to [another Emacs theme](https://github.com/donderom/jazz-theme), and I noticed I had several hard coded color strings which I used with my previous theme. I'm looking for a way to use `:inherit` and thus have those hard coded strings in one place.

```el
(make-face 'me/header-face)
(set-face-attribute 'me/header-face nil
                    :background 'unspecified :foreground solarized/blue
                    :italic nil :underline nil :weight 'bold)

(set-face-attribute 'helm-source-header nil :inherit 'me/header-face)
```

But some additonnal style is being applied to `'helm-source-header`.

[image: emacs.header-face]

It appears that the Solarized theme applies his own attributes. How do I tell I only want my own definitions ?

Comment: The colors are lines 51 to 92 of the source code that you attached.  Are you interested in changing the values of any of those?  Or, are you interested in adding additional settings such as underlines and so forth?

Comment: Yeah example in the picture is using `solarized-theme`, but `jazz-theme` is also adding his own attributes to faces. How would I use `me/header-face`'s attributes only ? Furthermore, am I getting the good approach to do that ?

Comment: Why not just manually edit lines 355 to 359 -- hard code the theme to use your preferred colors?

Comment: Because I install themes from MELPA.

Comment: I'm sure someone here will help you find an alternative method, but you should not be afraid to open up source code and modify it -- lines 355 to 359 are fairly straight forward.  If you need to re-byte compile with `M-x byte-compile-file`, you can do that too.

Comment: I'm not afraid about doing so, but I don't want to edit *vendor* files everytime I update them :/.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20557/discussion-between-mathieu-marques-and-lawlist).

Comment: Looks like you've deleted your comment. Omitting `:inherit` gives me: `set-face-attribute: Invalid face attribute name: me/header-face`

Comment: I would redefine it *without* using `:inherit` (aka **merge**):  `(set-face-attribute 'helm-source-header nil :background 'unspecified :foreground solarized/blue :italic nil :underline nil :weight 'bold)`  The attribute `:inherit` means:  *The name of a face from which to inherit attributes, or a list of face names. Attributes from inherited faces are **merged** into the face like an underlying face would be, with higher priority than underlying faces. If a list of faces is used, attributes from faces earlier in the list override those from later faces.*

Comment: Yeah this is how it was first. But there are several faces that I want to look the same. So I was looking for a way to factor what is likely to change everytime I change my theme.

Comment: I think there's something that can be worked out using [`face-all-attributes`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Attribute-Functions.html) but I am missing the part where I give its output in the correct format (something like `**params` if you're familiar with Python syntax).

Comment: Yup :), feel free to write this as an actual answer (with correct indenting cause that's something I'm not sure about).

Comment: The draft needs a little more work . . . I'll continue to give it some thought, and perhaps one of the experts will post an answer in the meantime.

Comment: Ok sounds good. Another thing: why can't I define my face with: `(defface me/header '((t :foreground green)) "Asdf.")` (no error on eval, but no style applied)? But it works with `make-face` + `set-face-attribute`.

Comment: @MathieuMarques you should be able to define a face like that. If you can't, something's wrong.

Comment: It looks like you are missing a set of parentheses around the attributes, and green is not a variable so it needs to be in double-quotes.  **Example**:  `(defface my-active-region-face '((t (:background "gray30" :foreground "white"))) "Face for 'my-active-region-face'." :group 'my-ruler-faces)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the same buffer as the screenshot you provide, toggle off each of the attributes you don't want and save it. In your case, you should toggle off everything but the `inherit` item.

The `customize` interface always gives priority to user customizations. So, the theme's definition will be overriden by yours for that specific face. In fact, even if you later change to another theme which applies different attributes to that face, your saved customization will still take precedence.

Comment: Accepting because this works. But I ended up doing what I got on http://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/2tmysv/how_can_i_overwrite_my_themes_colors/co0yghp. Thanks : )

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to enable more than one theme at a time. If you create a theme (using `deftheme`) that contains the your face definitions you can enable it at the same time as any package theme you want to use.

For example, in my `.emacs.d` I have defined a theme called `pd-basic` that contains the faces I want to override. To use it with `zenburn` I call the following:

```el
(load-theme 'zenburn t t)
(load-theme 'pd-basic t t)
(custom-set-variables '(custom-enabled-themes '(pd-basic zenburn)))
```